# MFMessageComposeViewController not showing recipient box

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

In my app I have hidden the status bar and increased the navigation bar height by using navigation bar category. Using:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNav)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 64);
    return newSize;
}

@end
```

so the view looks like:

[image]

Problem arises when I show the MFMessageComposeViewController view on top, maybe its assuming that the status bar is there and showing a black background:

[image]

Any work around or proper solution to fix this?

**UPDATE:**
As per solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927337/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-not-properly-displayed) I am hiding/showing status bar. But the black strip is still there (with same height as it is). Also tried by undoing the category on uinavigationbar. So the issue is not with the status bar and the custom navigationbar. What I am observing here is that black strip is at a place where the recipient numbers are supposed to be shown. Is there something that I am not using properly?

**Note:** the navigation bar i am using is opaque, not translucent

[image]

Comment: show status bar when you display/present `MFMessageComposeViewController` and hide status bar when didssmiss

Comment: @iPatel it doesnt seem like problem is with the status bar.. see the update

Comment: check this may be it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945390/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-7-statusbar-are-black

Comment: thanks! it was due to a setting [[uinavigationbar appearance] setbackground image...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was due to this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:...] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20564496/928763)